# NumberUtils.isCreatable(String) - how to replace it?

Tags: java, string, numeric, apache-commons

I want to check if some string is number or not.
I have a case where '0' is first digit of string and then '9' or '8' is second digit.
For example: **"0994545", "084354"**.

I am using *NumberUtils.isCreatable(String)*  from Apache commons 3 library.

Result:

```
NumberUtils.isCreatable("0994545"); //returns FALSE but it should be TRUE
NumberUtils.isCreatable("084354"); //returns FALSE but it should be TRUE
```

How can I replace NumberUtils to check if some string is number or not by not using NumberUtils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-hexadecimal strings beginning with a leading zero are treated as octal values. As crystal clearly seen, your input values are not valid octal values. [Source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks. For replacement I used NumberUtils.isParsable(String)